# Change Deployment config from shell

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I need to vary the deployment config of an application, by adding an extra YAML section within it (in the example the section name: **ping** and its two attributes)

```
containers:
- name: openshift-wf-cluster
image: 172.30.1.1:5000/demo/openshift-wf@sha256:5d7e13e981f25b8933d54c8716d169fadf1c4b9c03468a5b6a7170492d5b9d93
ports:
- containerPort: 8080
  protocol: TCP
- name: ping
  containerPort: 8888
  protocol: TCP
```

Is it possible to do it from the **oc** shell command ?(without manually editing the file) A sort of adding an extra node to one section of the YAML ?

Comment: See the ``oc patch`` command.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `oc patch` command to achieve this. See `oc patch --help` for more info. Try the following with your own deployment config name:

`oc patch dc/YOURDC -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/ports/1", "value":{"name":"ping","containerPort":8888,"protocol":"TCP"}}]' --type=json`

Answer (score -3):

Yes. You can edit your deployment config in place with the openshift tools

`oc edit dc/deployment-1-name` will open an editor for you to change your config.

Comment: While this snippet may address the immediate question we prefer to have some context as to why or how it does so.

Comment: Using ``oc edit`` means you are manually edit the resource definition, which seemed to be what they wanted to avoid.